# Jenkins reverse proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, jenkins, reverse-proxy

Background:

My company has Jenkins instance installed in Apache Tomcat behind the corporate firewall hosted on a CentOS box. say Box-A.

Port: 8080

Another Linux box, say Box-B is avialable and its clean. No Jenkins instance and no tomcat or Apache.

Requirement:

Is it possible to use the Box-B as the reverse proxy for the Jenkins on Box-A.
Like, `http://Box-B/jenkins` should route the traffic to `http://Box-A:8080`

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-http-https-reverse-proxy-load-balancer/

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/protect-your-ports-reverse-proxy?page=0,1
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Comment: Is box B inside or outside the corporate network? I mean:
Is box b able to reach your jenkins instance?